# Find Jordan canonical form with Kronecker product of JCF

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $f: K^3\to K^3$ be a map in Jordan canonical form having a matrix
$$\begin{pmatrix} 
2 & 1 & 0\\ 
0 &2&0\\
0&0&2\\
\end{pmatrix}$$
Find the JCF of the map $f\otimes f$.

So, since the matrix is already in JCF, the diagonal must be all 4, and thus all the eigenvalues must be 4. So, how to find the size for each block? Do I really have to do the JCF for a $9 \times 9$ matrix? or I need to use some property of the relationship between JCF of $f\otimes f$ and the JCF of $f$?

Comment: I found a good notes http://digitalcommons.unf.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1025&context=etd But I don't know how to use it(page 48 Thm 56). My problem is such a corner case, with all the eigenvalue 2 and not diagonalizable.